# OOP Help - How do I get this code block to recognize one of its arguments?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm learning Lua and how to implement OOP. Trying out a test example of an object seems to return one of the argument of the object as 'null' despite being assigned one.

```
function Character(Name, Level, Class)   --Constructor
    return {GetName = T.GetName, GetLevel = T.GetLevel, GetClass = T.GetClass}
  end
end
-- Snippets
Player = Character("Bob", 1, "Novice")
```

When I try printing **Player.GetName()** it returns null instead of **Bob**. Where have I gone wrong?

Here is [the full code](https://pastebin.com/mZaQ07JA).

Comment: `Character()` doesn't store its parameters anywhere.

Comment: How do I get it to store to be reused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOP in Lua takes a bit more than what you have done there, you will want to make use of metatables and upvalues.

```
-- How you could define your character structure.
local Character = {}

function Character.GetName(self)
  return self.name
end

function Character.new(Name, Level, Class)
  local _meta = {}
  local _private = {}
  _private.name = Name
  _private.level = Level
  _private.class = Class

  _meta.__index = function(t, k) -- This allows access to _private
    return rawget(_private, k) or rawget(Character, k)
  end

  _meta.__newindex = function(t, k, v) -- This prevents the value from being shaded
    if rawget(_private, k) or rawget(Character, k) then
      error("this field is protected")
    else 
      rawset(t, k, v)
    end
  end
  return  setmetatable({}, _meta) --return an empty table with our meta methods implemented 
end
```

This creates a local table `_private` when you create a new instance of a `Character`. That local table is an upvalue to the `_meta.__index` and it cannot be accessed outside the scope of the `Character.new` function. `_private` can be accessed when `__index` is called because it is an upvalue.

```
-- How to use the character structure 
player = Character.new("Bob", 10, "Novice")
npc = Character.new("Alice", 11, "Novice")
print(player:GetName())
```

I use `player:GetName()`, but in all honesty you can just do `player.name` as well.

Resources for more on this topic:

> http://tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_metatables.htm
>
> http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial

Comment: Is there an additional explanation for meta tables or a website you recommend for it? The book I'm reading discusses that term far later, but your answer is useful and now has me curious to learn more if it pertains to this particular solution.

Comment: @FranciscoLumeSkaar quick breakdown of metatables: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_metatables.htm, i would also suggest this tutorial on oop in Lua: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientationTutorial